# Conecting R with php

Tags: php, r

I am trying to run a code of R in php localhost way; so I followed this example (https://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-php-and-r/).

```
<?php
// poorman.php

echo "<form action='poorman.php' method='get'>";
echo "Number values to generate: <input type='text' name='N' />";
echo "<input type='submit' />";
echo "</form>";

if(isset($_GET['N']))
{
  $N = $_GET['N'];

  // execute R script from shell
  // this will save a plot at temp.png to the filesystem
  exec("Rscript my_rscript.R $N");

  // return image tag
  $nocache = rand();
  echo("<img src='temp.png?$nocache' />");
}
?>

and the R script…

# my_rscript.R

args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

N <- args[1]
x <- rnorm(N,0,1)

png(filename="temp.png", width=500, height=500)
hist(x, col="lightblue")
dev.off()
```

I have both files in  /var/www/html/R folder; when I ran the php file goes perfectly but que I submit the number of "N" it did not show the same as the example web image.

I also tried to run only to show a rnorm() distribution but I have the same results -> nothing.

I think that my problems is in coneccting R with php so I tried installation Rapache (http://rapache.net/manual.html) but when I reach 
"sudo apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev apache2-mpm-prefork libapreq2-dev r-base-dev"
I received the following message -> could not find package apache2-prefork-dev

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance

George

Answer (score 1):

Recreating your issue, the Apache error log returned:

> 'Rscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

This indicates the Apache server does not recognize the system environment variables. You might be running Apache in a different environment than your OS where most likely you have Rscript in your `PATH` variable. See how to set system environment variables in Apache which may involve adjusting the httpd.conf or .htaccess files.

However, consider the quick resolution in pointing to absolute path of the Rscript executable:

```
exec("path/to/R/bin/Rscript my_rscript.R $N");
```

For me, doing so yielded the appropriate output:

[image: RScript Plot Output]

Comment: I have serial troubles to connect it because I am starting with programming. I don´t know what you mean when you said  "running Apache in a different environment than your OS where most likely you have Rscript" I am using ubuntu 16.04. Besides, where can I find the files that you said. what I achieved was to save the image in the same folder so the php could read it. I would appreciate i anyone could explain me how to work the example like i were a 5th grade school boy. thanks.

Comment: Did you try the solution where you simply add the full path of Rscript to your PHP's `exec()` line?

Comment: I think so. I have both files in a folder called "machine" with the following path [ /var/www/html/machine ] and in my poorman.php file the exec() part is written like this: exec("/var/www/html/machine/ my_rscript.R $N"); I tried joining my_srcript to the complete path and also letting a space between them. If I run my_rcript.R in R a temp,png file is created in this folder but i cant do it from the php.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted, I meant full path of Rscript.exe not your R script but the executable program (usually found in bin folder of installation directory). The problem is your PHP cannot find the *Rscript* environment variable , so needs absolute one (in Unix, do not include .exe extension). See answer here that does that. Give that a try.

Comment: I did what you recommended but without success.                                                                                                      // execute R script from shell
 // this will save a plot at temp.png to the filesystem
 exec("/usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript my_rscript.R $N");                                                                                                            this is what i wrote in the php file but no image returned. I also tried writing .exe after the Rscript with the same result. It is ok that both files must be in the same folder? thanks in advance.

Comment: Executable and R script does not need to be in same folder but the PHP script and R script must be if using such an `exec()` command. Otherwise, you need to give a relative/absolute path to R script. For me, I placed PHP and R script in the **htdocs** of my Apache directory and opened the PHP link via localhost in browser where above image saved in htdocs and rendered in browser.

Comment: OK, the files must be together; so I had wrote the complete path as you see inside de exec("/usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript my_rscript.R $N") but nothing works. ideas?

Comment: How are you calling PHP? Don't call it locally but through Apache web server.

Comment: I use the "http://localhost/machine/poorman.php" to call every php that I creates that are allocated in the /var/www/html/, also in my apache2 folder there is no htdocs. I dont know other way to call php.

Comment: Check your Apache error log files which will give more details on why PHP did not render image.

Comment: now it works, i dont know what i have done. thanks for the help.

Comment: Interesting. Great to hear!  Please accept (tick mark to side) this answer to confirm resolution or answer your own question if something else was the reason.